# How to calculate sum of a specific column in a html table and display the sum using php echo in a <td> tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I am making a mark sheet page where number of mark sheets are displayed. I want to calculate sum of a column (which is just a text on the html page in a `<td>` tag).

[image: Example of Data]

this is the screenshot of the table. I want to display the sum of the (GP*CP) column in the blank space next to SGPA.

Also I have tried using Javascript but I couldn't call the Javascript function in the php echo `<td>` tag.

Also is there any other way ? Like storing the values of the `<td>` tag in a php variable and then echo-ing it?

Comment: Please update the answer with your code.

Comment: JavaScript is client-side. Php is server-side. Any data from one can't be accessed by the other unless it's transferred via HTTP. You can either sum with JS and display it or sum it with PHP and insert the sum into the document. No such thing as _"call the javascript function in the php echo tag"_.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change your text to an int variable so you are able to calculate the answer, Here is an example:

```
var a = parseInt("10") + "<br>";
var b = parseInt("10.00") + "<br>";
var c = parseInt("10.33") + "<br>";
var d = parseInt("34 45 66") + "<br>";
var e = parseInt(" 60 ") + "<br>";
var f = parseInt("40 years") + "<br>";
var g = parseInt("He was 40") + "<br>";

var h = parseInt("10", 10)+ "<br>";
var i = parseInt("010")+ "<br>";
var j = parseInt("10", 8)+ "<br>";
var k = parseInt("0x10")+ "<br>";
var l = parseInt("10", 16)+ "<br>";

var n = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + "<br>" + h + i + j + k +l;
```

Comment: I cannot do that because the values are dynamic.